# Download and Concatenate multiple files from database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have uploaded and stored multiple txt files into a SQL Server database. The idea here is that a user can select the files that they want and then have the C# code read the data from each file and create ONE text file with all the data from each selected. Then make the consolidated file available for download

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter("Filename");
    string SQL = "select Item from Table where ID in (1, 2, 3)";
    SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(SQL, Con);
    SqlDataReader Reader = Command.ExecuteReader();
    while (Reader.Read())
        Writer.WriteLine(Reader["Item"].ToString());
    Reader.Close();
    Writer.Close();
```

Making the file available for download is another question.